# if body hasClass after DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am inserting some classes dynamically after the page loads. I need to check before a user saves their changes if a certain class exists which indicates empty fields.

I have this but it is not working and I am thinking it is because I am adding the classes to elements dynamically after the page loads.

```
if ($("body").hasClass("sq-input--error")) {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: try if($(".sq-input--error").length > 0)

Comment: Yup, make it an answer please so I can vote it

Comment: FYI, you don't need a library for this anymore. `if (document.querySelector(".sq-input--error")) { ...` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask jQuery if a selector for that class has any dom elements:

```
  if($(".sq-input--error").length > 0)
```